# Maintaining phase relationships and other general principles of interferometry

Tags: optics, interference, interferometry

I have a few confusions with some basic principles of interferometry.

1. Bob Campbell's *So you want to do VLBI* writes:

> Phase relationships among all points on the wavefront will be
>   preserved because all paths to the focus have the same length; it is
>   essentially this preservation of phase relationships over the
>   wavefront that provides us the ability to measure angles on the sky.

Why is measuring angles on the sky important to interferometry or people in general? If the phase relationship was lost (lines coming to the focus point didn't all have the same length), why would this not be able to be satisfied?

2. When two antennae connected by baseline $b$ receive a plane wavefront propagating in a direction *not* perpendicular to the baseline, whether destructive or constructive interference occurs depends on the path difference between the two signals that reached either antenna. I suppose it's easiest for me to imagine approximating the two antenna as one huge antenna with diameter $b$, with an incident plane wave off-axis causing non-perfect constructive interference at the focal point. If you vary this off-axis angle, an interference pattern will be found. Why is this important to us in the first place? You could use trigonometry to find this off-axis angle, but why do we care about it in the first place?